# Picasso loading duplicate images

Tags: java, android, picasso

Ive searched and cant find anything to do with this problem im getting, im loading images into multiple grid views each inside a tabbed page view. Performance is great but any grid view that has lots of images and needs to scroll the images loaded are incorrect, it dublicates images and loads them into the wrong position. Below is one of the adapters im using for the grid view:

```
 public class PcAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    private Integer[] imageIds = {
            R.drawable.pcserioussam, R.drawable.pc_trinetwo,
            R.drawable.pc_leftfordead, R.drawable.pc_dungeondefenders,
            R.drawable.pc_portaltwo, R.drawable.pc_spaz,
            R.drawable.pc_laracroftattoo, R.drawable.pc_goatsim,
            R.drawable.pc_deadblock, R.drawable.pc_dynasty,
            R.drawable.pc_minecraft, R.drawable.pc_kanelynch,
            R.drawable.pc_toy, R.drawable.pc_awesomenauts,
            R.drawable.pc_bioniccomm, R.drawable.pc_fastandfurious,
            R.drawable.gen_harryone, R.drawable.gen_harrytwo,
            R.drawable.gen_watchmen
    };

    public PcAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return imageIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView iview;

        if(view == null){
            iview = new ImageView(context);
            Picasso.with(context).load(imageIds[position]).
                                  placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).
                                  resize(230, 300).centerInside().into(iview);
        } else {
            iview = (ImageView) view;
        }
        return iview;
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your picasso code out of the if statement. Currently it will only load a new image if view is null? Put it at the bottom of the if statement just before the return statement.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted the problem perfectly, cant believe i didnt see that :s thanks again

Comment: He he no problem at all. Glad it helped you, sometimes we just need an extra pair of eyes to see the small things we miss. Happy coding!